# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel, Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

We have an Azure function running .net 5.0, but when trying to debug locally we are receiving the error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: I would start with the error message's assertion "The system cannot find the file specified" and conduct your troubleshooting accordingly.

Comment: Provide the Function code to see appropriate resolution and versions suitable for the fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the functions to version 4 (from 3) sorted it.